# Pandas, plotly heatmaps and matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using python 3.8, plotly 4.14.1, pandas1.2.0

I can't work out how to separate my data in pandas and assign data to counters so I can update a heatmap.

I want to create a risk matrix of impact x likelihood and have those numbers shown on a Plotly heat map.

Hard coding the data into the dataframe and it works as expected

below with figure factory

```
gross_data=[[0,1,2,6,3], [0,7,18,12,6], [6,10,43,44,7], [3,15,29,46,18], [5,14,26,22,21]]

x=['Minor [Very Low]<br>1', 'Important [Low]<br>2', 'Significant [Moderate]<br>3', 'Major [High]<br>4', 'Critical [Very High]<br>5']
y=['Very Remote<br>1', 'Remote<br>2', 'Unlikely<br>3', 'Possible<br>4', 'Highly Possible<br>5']

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(gross_data, x=x, y=y, colorscale='Magma')
fig['layout']['xaxis']['side'] = 'bottom'
fig.show()
```

Plotly Figfure Factory annotated heatmap
[image]

or doing it with plotly express

```py
gross_data=[[0,1,2,6,3], [0,7,18,12,6], [6,10,43,44,7], [3,15,29,46,18], [5,14,26,22,21]]

fig = px.imshow(gross_data,
                labels=dict(x="Impact", y="Probability", color="Number of Risks"),
                x=['Minor [Very Low]', 'Important [Low]', 'Significant [Moderate]', 'Major [High]', 'Critical [Very High]'],
                y=['Very Remote', 'Remote', 'Unlikely', 'Possible', 'Highly Possible']
               )
fig.update_xaxes(side="bottom")

fig.show()
```

Plotly Heat Map
[image]

Now, these both would do for a one-off presentation but I'd like to be able to slice and dice my data and display it by a business unit etc.

I am using pandas to read in about 1000 lines of excel data which has been filled out as a form by human complete with all the errors that brings. I have tidied them up and cleaned the data.

What I can't work out is how to get the data required to provide sizes for each of the cells in the risk matrix without having a massive if statement going something like the following.

```
for X in df[gross_impact]:
    for y in df[gross_likelihood]:
        if (x == 1) & (y == 1):
            increment a counter associated with cell x1y1
       elif (x == 2) & (y == 1):
            increment a counter associated with cell x2y1
       elif (x == 3) & (y == 1):
            increment a counter associated with cell x3y1
       elif (x == 4) & (y == 1):
            increment a counter associated with cell x4y1
       elif (x == 4) & (y == 1):
            increment a counter associated with cell x5y1
       elif (x == 1) & (y == 2):
            increment a counter associated with cell x1y2
       elif (x == 2) & (y == 2):
            increment a counter associated with cell x2y2
      .....
      .....
      elif (x == 5) & (y == 5):
        increment a counter associated with cell x5y5
```

This is obviously wholly inefficient. id run through about 233,000 loops to get my results and whilst compute resource is cheap, that doesn't make it right.

I just can't fathom out how I should do this. I have read a couple of stack exchange questions but they did not address my query. I've researched around the net looking for risk matrixes but that comes back in c++ or financial data stuff that does not look applicable.

My data frame has about 30 fields but the unique reference is risk_id. My fields that I am multiplying against each other are risk_impact and risk_likelihood. and I could sort on risk_id and business_unit

I have to differentiate between 1 x 3 and 3 x 1 as that goes into two different bins
Counting should be from bottom left to top right so 1 x 3 is column 1, row 3. 3 x 1 is column 3 row 1

Hopefully, that is clear. if I knew exactly what to ask for I may have done it

Any help with working this out would be greatly appreciated.

here is an example of the data i have in my datafrae

```
import pandas as pf

# Our data to be loaded into the data frame
data = {'risk_id': ['AP-P01-R01', 'AP-P02-R02', 'AP-P03-R03', 'AP-P01-R04', 'BP-P01-R01', 'BP-P01-R02', 'BP-P01-R03', 'BP-P01-R04', 'BP-P01-R05', 'BP-P01-R06', 'BP-P01-R07', 'CP-P01-R01', 'CP-P01-R02', 'CP-P01-R03', 'CP-P01-R04', 'CP-P01-R05', 'CP-P01-R06', 'CP-P01-R07', 'CP-P01-R08'],
        'gross_impact': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2],
        'gross_likelihood': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3],
        'business_unit': ['Accounts Payable', 'Accounts Payable', 'Accounts Payable', 'Accounts Payable', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'British Petroleum', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile', 'Client Profile']
        }
```

This all loads in fine

[image: Loaded dataframe]

Using the solution provided worked perfectly on my limited dataset.
When i created a mere pandas dataframe using my master file i get the following error

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

The error appers when i run the code and its the  following line that throws an
error

```
heatmap[counts[:,1]-1, counts[:,0]-1] = counts[:,2]
```

the full code I am running is

```
df = raca_df[['risk_id', 'gross_impact','gross_likelihood', 'business_unit']].dropna()
counts = df.groupby(['gross_impact','gross_likelihood']).apply(len).reset_index().values

heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(5), np.max(5)))
#heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(df['gross_impact']), np.max(df['gross_likelihood'])))
heatmap[counts[:,1]-1, counts[:,0]-1] = counts[:,2]

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(heatmap)
fig['layout']['xaxis']['side'] = 'bottom'
fig.show()
```

After being prompted on how i created raca df a quick raca_df.info pointed out my issue. This turned out to be a problem with my original raca_df dataframe and the column type being float64. I also had some blank entries in the column so it would not let me change the column type there.

I had to create a new data frame from raca_df imaginitivly called df and i changed the column types there using a loop and astype('int')

```
df = raca_df[['risk_id', 'gross_impact','gross_likelihood', 'business_unit']].dropna()

for item in ['gross_impact','gross_likelihood', 'net_impact', 'net_likelihood']:
    raca_df[item] = raca_df[item].astype('int')
```

Comment: hi. please provide an example of your data

Comment: Example data added

Comment: how did you define `raca_df`?

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I just annotated the question. I have now fixed the issue. my original columns were float62, but I could not change them to int as there were blank values in the columns. when I created the df dataframe i then dropped the blankel values via .dropna I was then able to amment the column type and it all now works perfectly. again thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group by  impact and likelihood and use groupsize to get your heatmap intensities:

```
counts = df.groupby(['gross_impact','gross_likelihood']).apply(len).reset_index().values

# then, you can initialise an empty heatmap and use fancy indexing to populate it:    
heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(df['gross_impact']), np.max(df['gross_likelihood'])))
heatmap[counts[:,0]-1, counts[:,1]-1] = counts[:,2]

# and finally plot it
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(heatmap)
fig.show()
```

edit:

for individual business units, you can run the same code, with either of these tweaks:

```
# for a single business unit
counts = df[df['business_unit']=='Accounts Payable'].groupby(['gross_impact','gross_likelihood']).apply(len).reset_index().values

# and then the remaining code


# for all units, you can loop:
for business_unit in set(df['business unit']):
    counts = df[df['business unit']==business_unit].groupby(['gross_impact','gross_likelihood']).apply(len).reset_index().values
    
    # and then the remaining code
```

Comment: great! let me know if anything is still unclear

Comment: Hey warped. Thanks for that that works well. I have played around with it and I think I understand most of it.

I modified the second line to 

"heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(5), np.max(5)))"

as there was a possibility that there would be no impacts and likelihoods of 5 and therefore the matrix might shrink.

Can you explain the indexing? I played around with it changing data to see the effect but on looking at the Plotly FigureFactory create_annotated_heatmap I cant see how the matrix being mapped. are we just mapping values and heatmap takes care of x and y?

Comment: Can you also point me in the direction of how i would pull a subset out for a single business unit heat map?

Comment: if you look at `counts`, you will see that it has 3 columns. These originate, respectively from `gross_impact`, `gross_likelihood` and the groupsize. `gross_impact` is interpreted as row-index, `gross_likelihood` as column index, and the value that is assigned is the group size. The -1 corrects for the fact that python indexing starts iwth 0.

Comment: Thanks so much for your tutelage. I have learned a tonne from this. definitely beets my loop idea :)

Comment: so im still getting a problem when i try and do it with my live data
df = raca_df[['risk_id', 'gross_impact','gross_likelihood', 'business_unit']].dropna()
counts = df.groupby(['gross_impact','gross_likelihood']).apply(len).reset_index().values

heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(5), np.max(5)))
#heatmap = np.zeros((np.max(df['gross_impact']), np.max(df['gross_likelihood'])))

heatmap[counts[:,1]-1, counts[:,0]-1] = counts[:,2]

returns the following error

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
ideas?

Comment: can you edit your question with that error. which line is throwing it?

Comment: Edited the question and added trhe annomaly to the end.